# Understanding relationship between heading, pitch, roll to phi omega kappa?

Tags: coordinate-system, references

I am trying to find some good online reference (formulas, perhaps a script) on the relationship between heading, pitch, roll to phi omega kappa. In my current situation i receive camera orientations (and positions in world frame) in the hybrid notation (1x extrinsic then 2x intrinsic) of heading pitch roll, which refer to the local tangent plane. I have some other data i want to superimpose into the images which are provided in the UTM "world" frame so the data is not directly combinable. For this i would like to have the camera orientations in the phi omega kappa notation which correspond to the world UTM frame. There is a whole mess of different notations and definitions of angles in this topic which makes everything very confusing.

Does someone have a good reference on this?

Particulary conversion of HPR to OPK?